# Rapidly assigned game management in a database with many connections

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, redis, server

I want to run a server that can rapidly assign game data.

The simple model is:

```
P1 joins
P2 joins
Make a game with P1 & P2
P3 joins
P4 joins
Make a game with P3 & P4
etc..
```

but the advanced design is to have logic associated with the pairings.

For example:

```
P1 (A) joins.
P2 (B) joins.
P3 (C) joins.
P4 (A) joins.
Make game with P1 & P4
etc..
```

So far I've been using Node + Mongo.js but it seems odd to me to read and write to the database. Is this something that would be better served by using in-memory structures? Should I look at Redis?

I'm looking for efficiency here. It doesn't have to be for billions of connections but should tolerate say, the world's chess population playing speed chess games matching against similar ELO rankings.

Comment: I'm sure this can be done in a number of ways - please expand on "logic associated with the pairings" to get any sort of meaningful answers.

Comment: I'm looking for the overall structure. Say it just matches by similar ELO ratings, or a flag like in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this something that would be better served by using in-memory structures? Should I look at Redis?

That probably mostly depends on how long your players are willing to *wait*. It doesn't seem to make much sense to store waiting player persistently, so redis or even a redis without persistence might be a better fit indeed.

> [...] but should tolerate say, the world's chess population playing speed chess games matching against similar ELO rankings

Whatever that means... 5M? 10M? Whatever it is, you can get 16GB of RAM at a decent price, so millions usually isn't too troublesome unless you store tens of thousands of bytes per entry.

Comment: Sure, 5 million sounds reasonable.  What kind of latency do you see node.js having at this scale?

Comment: Looking up another entry with the same 'game type' ('A', 'B', 'C') could be done trough a hashtable or a hash index. The time that takes depends mostly on implementation details since it's asymptotically O(1). The constant time should be in the microseconds regime, so your network latency will be many orders larger than that. No need to worry...